# Why lxc container doesn't execute config files on /etc/sysctl.d?

Tags: lxc, sysctl

My host is Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with privileged container.

I want to disable ipv6 of container, so I created a config file on `/etc/sysctl.d/60-disable-ipv6.conf`, I have tried `lxc-start` and `lxc-stop -r` my container, container's ipv6 is not disabled until run `sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/60-disable-ipv6.conf`, it works, ipv6 address is disabled.

Why container doesn't load `/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf`?

Comment: is this container running in privileged mode? this might affect its ability to change sysctl parameters. also the `systemd-sysctl.service` might be disabled - if available at all.

Comment: does `systemctl status systemd-sysctl.service` tell you anything about the service and if it failed?

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann Thanks! systemctl told me that service didn't start, because `ConditionPathIsReadWrite=/proc/sys/ was not met`, so I added `lxc.mount.auto = proc` or `lxc.mount.auto = proc:rw`, it doesn't work, I still could view `/proc/sys` in container.

Comment: Can you please retry with a privileged container? https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/getting-started/#creating-privileged-containers

Comment: I'm using privileged container. I found this, https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4370

Comment: great, so you need a systemd version of v232 or later - OR you can fix it by changing that line in `systemd-sysctl.conf` yourself ;-)

ahh ... and you should add this as an answer to your own question

Comment: Maybe. I changed systemd-sysctl.service condition to /proc/sys/net, it works, but systemd-sysctl executed failed, maybe something else wrong

Answer (score 1):

Thnaks Phillip's instruction, I found `systemd-sysctl.service` didn't start in container with this message: `ConditionPathIsReadWrite=/proc/sys/ was not met`

I have tried `lxc.mount.auto=proc` and `lxc.mount.auto=proc:rw` in lxc config, but it doesn't work for me.

Last I found there is an issue of `systemd`:https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4370, maybe if I could install `systemd v232` it solves.(modify `systemd-sysctl.service`:  `ConditionPathIsReadWrite` to `/proc/sys/net` could solve it.)

I added `sudo sysctl --system` on a start up script, it works.